# How to remove all table rows (from if statement), not only even/odd in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a big form, so I would like to be able to remove all empty rows in my table before sending it by email.

Basically I'm looking for all inputs with 'elem' class than I try to remove whole rows with empty input.

But as you can see in this fiddle only odd rows are removed:

```js
  var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('elem');
      for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].value == '') {
          inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode);
          }
        }
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #989898;
}

input {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th><th>Col5</th><th>Col6</th><th>Col7</th><th>Col8</th><th>Input</th></tr>
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Name<input type="hidden" name="1" value="1 - Name "></td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td><input type="number" class="elem" name="1-1" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Name<input type="hidden" name="2" value="2 - Name"></td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td><input type="number" class="elem" name="2-2" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Name<input type="hidden" name="3" value="3 - Name"></td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td><input type="number" class="elem" name="3-3" value=""></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>4</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Name<input type="hidden" name="4" value="4 - Name "></td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>Text</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td>-</td>
  <td><input type="number" class="elem" name="4-4" value=""></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Note:** I do not have any problems with sending it or triggering this action after submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Live Collection

**Use [`document.querySelectorAll('.elem')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) instead of <del>`document.getElementsByClassName('elem')`</del>**

Old methods such as `.getElementsByClassName()`, `.getElementsByTagName()`, and `.getElementsByName()` return a [***Live Collection*** (see item 8.)](http://jonraasch.com/blog/10-javascript-performance-boosting-tips-from-nicholas-zakas). A Live Collection updates immediately thereby affecting its own `.length` on every iteration of the `for` loop and shifting references which cause unexpected results such as odd positioned elements being removed and even positioned elements being skipped.

#### Live Collection in a `for` loop

1. **First iteration** `input.length = 4`

   - `for (let i = 0;` **0** `<` **4** `i++) {...`
2. **The first row `<input>` is removed and now** `input.length = 3`

   - `inputs[` **0** `].closest('tr').remove()`
3. **Second iteration** `i = 1` **but** `inputs[1]` **is not the second row** `<input>` **anymore it is now** `input[0]` **so it's skipped and not removed.**

   - `for (let i = 0;` **1** `<` **3** `i++) {...`
4. **The third row** `<input>` **is removed and now** `input.length = 2`

   - `inputs[` **1** `].closest('tr').remove()`
5. **Third iteration** `i = 2` **but** `inputs[2]` **does not exist because there's only 2** `<input>` **left** (***remember `input.length = 2`***).

   - `for (let i = 0;` **2** `<` **2** `i++) {...`
6. **The fourth row** `<input>` **is never touched because its now** `inputs[1]`

   - `inputs[` **2** `].closest('tr').remove()`
7. **Fourth iteration** `i = 3` **and** `input.length = 2` **which completes the `for` loop.**

   - `for (let i = 0;` **3** `<` **2** `i++) {...`

`document.querySelectorAll()` returns a *"static"* NodeList that does not update during runtime thereby keeping all DOM references from shifting.

**Demo 1** is the OP code with `document.querySelectorAll()` and **Demo 2** is a better version with [`for...of` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of), [`.closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest), and [`.remove()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ChildNode/remove)

#### Demo 1

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.elem');
for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].value == '') {
    inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(inputs[i].parentNode.parentNode);
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #989898;
}

input {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th><th>Col5</th><th>Col6</th><th>Col7</th><th>Col8</th><th>Input</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Text</td><td>Name<input type="hidden" name="1" value="1 - Name "></td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><input type="number" class="elem" name="1-1" value=""></td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Text</td><td>Name<input type="hidden" name="2" value="2 - Name"></td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><input type="number" class="elem" name="2-2" value=""></td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Text</td><td>Name<input type="hidden" name="3" value="3 - Name"></td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><input type="number" class="elem" name="3-3" value="4"></td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Text</td><td>Name<input type="hidden" name="4" value="4 - Name "></td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><input type="number" class="elem" name="4-4" value=""></td></tr></table>
```

#### Demo 2

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.elem');

for (let input of inputs) {
  if (!input.value) {
    input.closest('tr').remove();
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #989898;
}

input {
  width: 60px;
  height: 100%;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<table><tr><th>Col1</th><th>Col2</th><th>Col3</th><th>Col4</th><th>Col5</th><th>Col6</th><th>Col7</th><th>Col8</th><th>Input</th></tr><tr><td>1</td><td>Text</td><td>Name<input type="hidden" name="1" value="1 - Name "></td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><input type="number" class="elem" name="1-1" value=""></td></tr><tr><td>2</td><td>Text</td><td>Name<input type="hidden" name="2" value="2 - Name"></td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><input type="number" class="elem" name="2-2" value=""></td></tr><tr><td>3</td><td>Text</td><td>Name<input type="hidden" name="3" value="3 - Name"></td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><input type="number" class="elem" name="3-3" value=""></td></tr><tr><td>4</td><td>Text</td><td>Name<input type="hidden" name="4" value="4 - Name "></td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>Text</td><td>-</td><td>-</td><td><input type="number" class="elem" name="4-4" value=""></td></tr></table>
```

Comment: Super useful answer! Thanks for thorough explanation. Everything is working perfectly.

Comment: Glad I could help. Happy coding!

Comment: Sorry for grave digging. I had a problem with second method lately. Default value of the input was set to "" and everything was working fine. Until some user increased value, then decreased to 0. Then form is sending rows with value=0. I've switched to first method as it is fairly understandable, but how could I do the same with second one? I've tried !inputs.value = '0', !inputs.value(0) - and many variation of it but it's not working. Note that I've defaulted input value to "0" not "".

Comment: Sorry, It's been a while since I answered this question... Is 0 a valid criterion for row deletion? If so, then try changing `if (!input.value) {...` to `if (Number(input.value) < 1) {...` When any form control has data, it is an actual String not a Number. So keep that in mind when comparing data for conditions. A "0" in an input is a String character that represents a zero *but* not a real Number with a true value of the Number 0. Therefore, the "0" should be converted to a real Number ex. `Number(x.value)` or `parseInt(x.value, 10)`, or `parseFloat(x.value)`, or `x.valueAsNumber`